# Setting expiry on static resources with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, expires-header

just got to know that setting expiry dates for static resources make your site go fast and jump in rankings.

My question is:

1. Does browser checks create date of the static resource?
2. If I make change to a css before 1 month, does server sends fresh copy and browser refreshes its cache?

This is the code I added to htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Use `modified plus 1 month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [mod_expires documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_expires.html):

> The expiration date can set to be relative to either the time the source file was **last modified**, or to the time of the **client access**.

Here is the syntax:

```
ExpiresByType type/encoding "base[plus num type] [num type] ..."
```

> where base is one of:
>
> - access
> - now (equivalent to 'access')
> - modification
>
> The `plus` keyword is optional. `num`  should be an integer value [acceptable to `atoi()`], and `type` is one of:
>
> - years
> - months
> - weeks
> - days
> - hours
> - minutes
> - seconds

---

So if you write:

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
```

Your file will be cached as long as visitors keep requesting it without interruption for more than a month, even if you modify it.

---

You should then write instead:

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "modification plus 1 month"
```

Then your file will be cached for a month as long as it is not modified, otherwise the cache will be updated.